# JavaScript XmlHttpRequest with Keep-Alive on Android

Tags: javascript, android, xmlhttprequest, cordova, keep-alive

I am trying to build a website (intended to be put into a PhoneGap app) that displays messages it is sent via HTTP push (long polling, comet, ..). For this I need a connection that is kept alive by the client. However, the Android browser seems to always close the connection immediately and does not allow me to set the Connection: keep-alive HTTP header.

Is there a possibility to connect to the server and keep the connection alive?

Thanks in advance :)
M.T.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to use an implementation of some kind of HTML5 Websocket. So far as I know, there's no direct implementation of that WebKit feature in Gingerbread 2.3.x yet, nor Phonegap but there's a workaround by library in Phonegap:

http://anismiles.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/websocket-support-in-android%E2%80%99s-phonegap-apps/

Happy coding!
Martin

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your quick response. I also thought about WebSockets. However, I am bound to an unmodified lighttpd, plus my app should not only work on Android but also on WP7 and bada, which makes it hard to work with WebSockets.

Comment: A good-looking library I found while searching for WS support is socket.io. Seems a bit buggy at the moment, but could be great.